# java - Problem with removing object from List

Tags: java, list

I have a problem with deleting an object from List:
problem is, when choosing option 3:
"delete specific contact"
it's show me the object which I want to delete,
but the delete does not happen to the object in the file.

Update 1 : I understood that i need to realate the List to the file,
any suggestion for how doing it?
Update 2: I thought about just overwrite the file, how can i call all the list,
instead of only one object - ListName.get(number of object in list )
Update 3: Because i didn't find any way to get all the list, did just like that

```
for (int i = 0; i <contacts.size() ; i++) {
            if (i==0) {
                IO.write(fileName, contacts.get(i));
            }if (i>=1){
                IO.append(fileName,"\n"+ contacts.get(i));
            }
        }
```

Is it the way i should slove problems like this?

This is what in my Programs class

```java
public static void phoneBookAdding(){
    String name = IO.getString("enter your name");
    String phone = IO.getString("Enter your phone number");

    try {
        IO.write("PhoneBook","name: "+name + ", phone number: "+phone);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void deletePhoneBookContact(String fileName) throws IOException{
    List<String> contacts = IO.read(fileName);
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    int contactToRemove = IO.getInt("enter number of contact your want to delete from list");
    System.out.println("removed contact :"+ contacts.get(contactToRemove) );
    contacts.remove(contactToRemove);
}
```

and this is what in my Main class

```java
//getting choice for the program
int choiceForPhoneBook=0;
while (choiceForPhoneBook!=4) {
    System.out.println("welcome to PhoneBook program");
    choiceForPhoneBook = IO.getInt("Enter choice for phoneBook program \n 1) create phone book with first contact \n 2) add contact" +
                                   "\n 3) delete specific contact \n 4) exit");
    if (choiceForPhoneBook == 1) {
        Programs.phoneBookAdding();
    }
    if (choiceForPhoneBook ==2) {
        String name = IO.getString("enter your name");
        String phone = IO.getString("Enter your phone number");
        try {
            IO.append("PhoneBook", "\n name: "+name + ", phone number: "+phone);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("there might be a problem, call doctor!");;
        }
    }
    if (choiceForPhoneBook==3){
        try {
            Programs.deletePhoneBookContact("PhoneBook");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("could not found contact which chosen in list");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `deletePhoneBookContact` isn't writing your changes back to the file, so why would you expect the file's contents to have changed?

Comment: You read a list from a file, then you delete the item from the list. That has nothing to do with the file, so of course the file doesn't change.

Comment: thanks a lot, how can i relate it to the file?

Answer (score 0):

There are few important things you need to understand here. The file content where the data is permanently stored (for example in hard drive). The List object that lives temporarily in RAM. These two are completely different and disconnected. When your program deals with List object, it only affects that temporary List. In order to update the File with changes to List data, the program has to explicitly deal with updating the File. File manipulation treating content as data, is a complex area itself. Your code snippet has references to other libraries, like `List<String> contacts = IO.read(fileName);` . You should consult that library to understand possible choices to write the data back again to the file.